# Enforcing RC4 cipher and testing enabled ciphers with OpenSSL

Tags: security, ssl, apache-2.4, openssl

I am trying to enable and enforce RC4 cipher on Apache 2.4 and I checked the http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/ssl/ssl_howto.html It says RC4 cipher can be enabled in one of the below two ways:

```
1. SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 
   SSLHonorCipherOrder on

2. SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+EXP:+eNULL
```

Which one is the better to enable and enforce RC4 cipher?

How do I test the enabled ciphers with openSSL?

Comment: No one of those will enforce RC4. The second activates all, the first activates all highs.

Answer (score 1):

You want to... *enable* RC4?  Is this for some sort of honeypot or something?  You really don't want to use it in normal use, because [RC4 is broken](https://community.qualys.com/thread/14956).

If you really want to, though, I *think* the way to enforce the use of RC4 would be just to make the cipher spec `RC4` by itself -- that'll enable all cipher combinations that include the use of RC4.  You may want to then disable some of the even-more-broken ciphers, like NULL and export-grade ciphers, as well as deprecated unnecessary ones like MD5, with something like `RC4:!MD5:!aNULL:!EXPORT`.

And may `$DEITY` have mercy on your soul...

Comment: MD5 *for HMAC* isn't broken last I heard, although SHA (meaning SHA1) is *better*; `!EXPORT` and `!aNULL` prevent dangers that would be worse, although good clients won't offer them anyway.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 good catch on export/NULL; I've added them to my answer.  As for HMAC-MD5, [RFC6151](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6151) says "it isn't quite broken yes, but don't use it for anything new".  Since I don't know of any reasonably popular SSL client implementation that *only* supports MD5, it seems prudent to get ahead of the curve and just turn 'em off now.